# What does this example code do?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I found this example on [jetbrains.com](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/08/25/typescript-and-javascript-in-resharper-9-2/)

```
async function getWeather(cityid: number){
    var weather = await getForecast(cityid);
    var {t: temperature, h: humidity} = weather;
    return { temperature, humidity};
}
```

I understand async/await, but I am trying to understand what is going on with the last two lines.

```
var {t: temperature, h: humidity} = weather;
```

As far as I can tell, this is creating a var with two properties, t of type temperature, and h of type humidity.

```
return { temperature, humidity};
```

To me, this looks like it is returning a new object with two child objects, temperature and humidity.  I don't get how it is getting that from the weather object.

I don't know if this is a javascript question, or a typescript question, so I am tagging as both.

Comment: This seems to be an [ES6 destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> var {t: temperature, h: humidity} = weather;

This is called *destructuring*. It is a concept covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/destructuring.html

Here you are saying put `weather.t` into `temprature` and `weather.h` into `humidity`

> return { temperature, humidity};

This is returning an object with properties `temprature` and `humidity`. This is shorthand for : `return { temperature:temperature, humidity:humidity};`. This is one of the new notations in ES6 : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: This answer was posted first ... and answered the second part of your question as well about object initializer shorthand (which the accepted answer doesn't) :-/ but on well 

Comment: You are correct, and I updated your answer to be the accepted one.

Answer (score 4):

`var {t: temperature, h: humidity} = weather;` is a very powerful new syntactic feature from ES6 called [destructing](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20&%20beyond/ch2.md#destructuring).

Assume that `weather` is an object `{ t: 60, h: 20 }`. Traditionally, when we want to assign the properties of `weather` into local variables, we would do something like:

```
var temperature = weather.temperature;
var humidity = weather.humidity;
```

This is really inconvenient and will be increasingly tiresome as the object grows more complex. With destructing, we can now use

```
var {t: temperature, h: humidity} = weather;
console.log(temperature); // 60
console.log(humidity); // 20
```

And have the local variables `temperature` and `humidity` already defined and ready for use.

Deconstructing also provides a shorter syntax for cases when the "target" variables are the same as the "source" variables. In the case of `weather`, instead of writing:

```
var {t: t, h: h} = weather;
console.log(t); // 60
console.log(h); // 60
```

We can just write:

```
var {t, h} = weather;
console.log(t); // 60
console.log(h); // 60
```